# How to listen for state change in SwitchCompat widget?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

How to listen for SwitchCompat widget clicks? I want to execute a few statements when the Switch is toggled.

Looking for an equivalent of

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        //Do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
static Boolean isTouched = false;

switchButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                isTouched = true;
                return false;
            }
        });

switchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if (isTouched) {
                isTouched = false;
                if (isChecked) {
                }
                else {
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Try this!

Comment: Okay, this won't let me restore the check. It restores it all right, but all the statements within onCheckedChanged are re-called. Looking for something that responds only to clicks. Not check changes.

Comment: Help me to understand, what exact behaviour do you want to archive from toggle button? button.setOnClickListener(...) - is fine for SwitchCompact - so why don't you wanna use it? i.e. 
    switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (switchButton.isChecked()) {
                    //do action

                 } else {
                    ...
                }

        }   
    });

Comment: `button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener..` doesn't respond to SwitchCompat.

Comment: It responds to clicks of the switch button. Not the swipe toggle.

Comment: Ok, but what do you want then? onClickListener listen to clicks, onCheckedChangeListener - listen to swipe toggle. Then what else left not covered by this 2 listeners?

Comment: I want to be able to swipe. Not click. If using onCheckedChangedListener, when state is restored, I don't want the statements within OnCheckeChanged(coumpoundButton, isChecked) to be executed. I just want to toggle without executing that particular function or the statements within it.

Comment: @user2474562 updated my answer. Now the code on toggle-button state changed is executed only if its "manual" triggered, not dynamically

Comment: If you drag the switch back and forth (without releasing the finger) your flag is set but not consumed, opening a window to set the checked state programmatically somewhere else.

Answer (score 14):

you need only this(the setOnTouchListener is unnecessary):

```
switchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {

                if (isChecked) {
                     //if 'isChecked' is true do whatever you need...
                }
                else {
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What if you want to check that the checked changed came from a user touch and not programmatically or from a data binding? Your statement is incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

**With Butterknife SwitchCompat state change**

```
  @OnCheckedChanged(R.id.switchCompat)
  public void onCheckedChanged(SwitchCompat switchCompat, boolean isChecked) {
    Log.i("skh", "check:" + isChecked);

    if (isChecked) {
        // Log.i("skh","check:"+isChecked);
    } else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Now it's possible to check with isPressed method within the same callback.

```
    switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
        if (buttonView?.isPressed == true) {
            // todo
        } else {
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem Slay explains on the comment to the accepted answer. Here the solution!

My solution, using a `SwitchCompat` and Kotlin. In my situation, i needed to react to a change only if the user triggered it through the UI. In fact, my switch reacts to a `LiveData`, and this made both `setOnClickListener` and `setOnCheckedChangeListener` unusable. `setOnClickListener` in fact reacts correctly to user interaction, but it's not triggered if the user drags the thumb across the switch. `setOnCheckedChangeListener` on the other end is triggered also if the switch is toggled programmatically (for example by an observer). Now in my case the switch was present on two fragments, and so onRestoreInstanceState would trigger in some cases the switch with an old value overwriting the correct value.

So, i looked at the code of SwitchCompat, and was able to mimic it's behaviour successfully in distinguishing click and drag and used that to build a custom touchlistener that works as it should. Here we go:

```
/**
 * This function calls the lambda function passed with the right value of isChecked
 * when the switch is tapped with single click isChecked is relative to the current position so we pass !isChecked
 * when the switch is dragged instead, the position of the thumb centre where the user leaves the
 * thumb is compared to the middle of the switch, and we assume that left means false, right means true
 * (there is no rtl or vertical switch management)
 * The behaviour is extrapolated from the SwitchCompat source code
 */
class SwitchCompatTouchListener(private val v: SwitchCompat, private val lambda: (Boolean)->Unit) :  View.OnTouchListener {
    companion object {
        private const val TOUCH_MODE_IDLE = 0
        private const val TOUCH_MODE_DOWN = 1
        private const val TOUCH_MODE_DRAGGING = 2
    }

    private val vc = ViewConfiguration.get(v.context)
    private val mScaledTouchSlop = vc.scaledTouchSlop
    private var mTouchMode = 0
    private var mTouchX = 0f
    private var mTouchY = 0f

    /**
     * @return true if (x, y) is within the target area of the switch thumb
     * x,y and rect are in view coordinates, 0,0 is top left of the view
     */
    private fun hitThumb(x: Float, y: Float): Boolean {
        val rect = v.thumbDrawable.bounds
        return x >= rect.left && x <= rect.right && y >= rect.top && y <= rect.bottom
    }

    override fun onTouch(view: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        if (view == v) {
            when (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event)) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    val x = event.x
                    val y = event.y
                    if (v.isEnabled && hitThumb(x, y)) {
                        mTouchMode = TOUCH_MODE_DOWN;
                        mTouchX = x;
                        mTouchY = y;
                    }
                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                    val x = event.x
                    val y = event.y
                    if (mTouchMode == TOUCH_MODE_DOWN &&
                        (abs(x - mTouchX) > mScaledTouchSlop || abs(y - mTouchY) > mScaledTouchSlop)
                    )
                        mTouchMode = TOUCH_MODE_DRAGGING;
                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> {
                    if (mTouchMode == TOUCH_MODE_DRAGGING) {
                        val r = v.thumbDrawable.bounds
                        if (r.left + r.right < v.width) lambda(false)
                        else lambda(true)
                    } else lambda(!v.isChecked)
                    mTouchMode = TOUCH_MODE_IDLE;
                }
            }
        }
        return v.onTouchEvent(event)
    }
}
```

How to use it:

the actual touch listener that accepts a lambda with the code to execute:

```
myswitch.setOnTouchListener(
    SwitchCompatTouchListener(myswitch) {
        // here goes all the code for your callback, in my case
        // i called a service which, when successful, in turn would 
        // update my liveData 
        viewModel.sendCommandToMyService(it) 
    }
)
```

For the sake of completeness, this is how the observer for the state `switchstate` (if you have it) looked like:

```
switchstate.observe(this, Observer {
    myswitch.isChecked = it
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you just need this:

```
if (yourSwitchButton.isChecked()) {
//do what you want here
} else{
//do what you want here
}
```

That's all!

Comment: This does not help since it does not listen to state changes. All it does is to check wheter the switch is checked or not.

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin, all you have to do is this:

```kotlin
switcher.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView: CompoundButton, isChecked: Boolean ->
    if (isChecked) {
        // Do something
    } else {
       // Do another thing
    }
}
```

That's because, even though the `` method expects an instance of the `OnCheckedChangeListener` interface, in kotlin, when a function receives an interfaces with only one function as a paramether, you can repret the given function.

Of course you can remove explicity lambda parameters types:

```kotlin
switcher.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->

}
```

Also, if you just want to use the isChecked value, you can replace the buttonView to _ like so:

```kotlin
switcher.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->

}
```